# Can't get data from client in FastAPI websocket | Python

Tags: python, websocket, fastapi

I get this error in my fastapi log:

```
INFO:     ('172.28.0.1', 35088) - "WebSocket /ws" [accepted]
INFO:     connection open
ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
...
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 58, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 580, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 297, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 68, in app
    await func(session)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 273, in app
    await dependant.call(**values)
    File "/code/./app/main.py", line 127, in websocket_endpoint
    data = await websocket.receive_text()
     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/websockets.py", line 85, in receive_text
     self._raise_on_disconnect(message)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/starlette/websockets.py", line 80, in _raise_on_disconnect
    raise WebSocketDisconnect(message["code"])
    starlette.websockets.WebSocketDisconnect: 1000
    INFO:     connection closed
```

I can't find the problem. Why my fastapi route can't get the data from client but the server message to client works.

**Client Code:**

```
import asyncio
from time import sleep
import websockets

async def get_work():
    async with websockets.connect("ws://localhost:3000/ws", open_timeout=None) as websocket:
        await websocket.send('Hello from CLient')
        answer = await websocket.recv()
        print(answer)
         
while True:
    asyncio.run(get_work())
    sleep(5)
```

**Server Code:**

```
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    while True:
        try:
            data = await websocket.receive_text()
            print(data)
        except RuntimeError:
            break
        await websocket.send_text("Hello from Server")
```

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Lol. I just notice that I get the string from client but I can't print it.